# If an iOS consumer denies permission to 'Use Current Location', is it technically possible to show the permission dialogue again?

Tags: ios, location, xamarin, spatial

My iOS app wants to display the users current location. Nothing special - but to do so, the first time the app is ran (or more to the point, the first time an `MKViewMap` in the app is displayed, I guess...) .. the user is asked for permission (which is awesome).

eg.

[image]

Now, if the user accidentally says DON'T ALLOW or decides to (later on) give permission ... is there technically a way we can reset their previous decision and when the app is restarted, ask them again automatically when the `MKViewMap` is next rendered again?

Answer (score 0):

The user can enable or disable that option in the setting of the iphone. To do this, user have to select the Privacy option in the Setting Menu, and then select the Location Services option and than search the desired app to whom user want to enable or disable the permission and perform desired function by switching the toggle button on or off.

Comment: Is it possible to check to see if the setting is off, in my app?

Comment: Yes, just run [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] (notice: class method). The result will be an enum (CLAuthorizationStatus).

Answer (score 0):

As it was a Private API provided from Apple the alert cannot be shown up again. Alternatively, we can check manually and show an alert like this.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be read in the Apple docs:
"...it is recommended that you always call the locationServicesEnabled class method of CLLocationManager before attempting to start either the standard or significant-change location services. If it returns NO and you attempt to start location services anyway, the system prompts the user to confirm whether location services should be re-enabled. Given that location services are very likely to be disabled on purpose, the user might not welcome this prompt."

If I understand it right the alert will pop up everytime you try to get the users location, but it's not recommended to do so.

Link to full post:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do so. Rather than this, you can just check the latitude and longitude value and show alert to the user that enable the service from settings.